# Express in terms of Fibonacci Numbers the number of $n$-term sequences of $0$s, $1$s, and $2$s such that $0$ is never immediately followed by $1$

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

> I've been tasked to express the following number in terms of the Fibonacci Numbers.
>
> The number of sequences $(δ_1, δ_2, . . ., δ_n)$ of $0$’s, $1$’s, and $2$’s such that $0$ is never immediately followed by $1$.

I can see using a chart that it should be $f_{2n+2}$

But I am struggling with coming up with a proof (in similar questions I have used bijections) to show it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n,b_n,c_n$ be the number of sequences $\{\delta_1,\cdots,\delta_n\}$ where the last element in the sequence $\delta_n$ equals $0,1,2$ respectively and satisfies the required condition. So our answer is the total, $T_n=a_n+b_n+c_n$.

According to the restrictions in your question, you have the following base cases: $$a_1=b_1=c_1=1, \qquad \qquad  a_2=3, b_2=2, c_2=3$$

and the following recursions: $$a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}\\b_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}\\c_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1} \tag{*}$$

**Proof**: the $a_n$ counts sequences $\{\delta_1,\cdots,\delta_{n-1},\delta_n=0\}$, so we counts $a_n$ by considering the cases where $\delta_{n-1}=0,1$ or $2$. There $a_{n-1},b_{n-1},c_{n-1}$ sequences of the form $\{\delta_1,\cdots,\delta_{n-1}\}$ where $\delta_{n-1}=0,1,2$ respectively, and for each of those sequences, we can append a $\delta_n=0$ to the end of it, to get a sequence counted in $a_n$. You can do similar counting arguments for the other two equations.

Now, note that from the base case and the recursion, we have $a_n=c_n \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, so the answer we actually need is $T_n=a_n+b_n+c_n=2a_n+b_n$

So we have from the set of equations in $(*)$ and the observation just made, $$a_n=2a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}=T_{n-1}\\ b_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}=b_{n-1}+T_{n-2} \quad (**)$$

which shows that the **total number of sequences satisfying the constraint, of length $n-1$ is precisely the number of sequences satisfying the constraint, of length $n$ that end in $0$**. Thus, the recursions become $$b_n=b_{n-1}+T_{n-2} \qquad \qquad (1)\\ T_{n-1}=2a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}\\ (\text{from }(**)) \quad =2(b_n-b_{n-1})+b_{n-1}=2b_n-b_{n-1} \quad (2)$$

$$ \implies T_{n-1}=b_n+(b_n-b_{n-1})=b_n+T_{n-2} \ (\text{from } (1),(2))\\ \implies b_n=T_{n-1}-T_{n-2} \qquad \qquad (3) \\ \implies b_{n-1}+T_{n-2}=T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}\ (\text{from } (1))\\ \implies T_{n-2}-T_{n-3}+T_{n-2}=T_{n-1}-T_{n-2} \ (\text{from } (3)) \\ \implies T_{n-1}=3T_{n-2}-T_{n-3}\qquad \qquad (4)$$
the indices in the recurrence in $(2)$ remind us of the Fibonacci sequence, in fact, if you tabulate a few values of $(b_i,T_i)$ for a few values of $i$, you will see that $(b_n,T_n)=(f_{2n-1},f_{2n+2})$.

Since you only need $T_n$, it suffices to prove by induction over $n$ that the sequence $\{f_{2n+2}\}_{n\ge 1}=\{3,8,21,55,\cdots\}$ satisfies recurrence $(4)$. You already have the base cases shown for $n=1,2$ at the very beginning of the answer.